# Best practice for using an external library on the window object

Tags: javascript, sdk, prebid.js

In my code I rely on an external library which I expect to be loaded on the `window` object on the pages where my snippet is going to be running. My code looks like the following:

```js
if (window.ats) {
        window.ats.retrieveEnvelope(function (envelope: string) {
          console.log('Located ATS.js');
          this.cachedEnvelope = JSON.parse(envelope).envelope;
        });
}
```

`ats` is the name of the library which I depend on. Locally this failed since `ats` is not one of the usual `window` properties. In order to make it compile and also be able to mock it in my tests, I created the following override:

```js
declare global {
  interface Window {
    ats?: any;
  }
}
```

I am wondering if this is the standard way to go about a situation like this. This (1) does make the code compile (2) should be able to allow the code identify the `ats` on a production environment and (3) allow mocking in the specs.

I am not a Javascript expert and I'd like to know if there's a better/standard way to address the aforementioned situation.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do so is to wait for the library to be loaded before using it :

```
var src= "https://yourlibrarypath";
var useSSL = document.location.protocol === 'https:';
var d = document, e = d.createElement('script'), p = d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
e.type = 'text/javascript';  e.async = true;
e.src = (useSSL ? 'https:' : 'http:') + src;
p.insertBefore(e, p.firstChild);

e.onload = function() {
  //library has been loaded...
}
```